# Gradle plugin google-services does not work with Cordova 8.0.0

Tags: firebase, cordova, push-notification, build.gradle

I'm Going to send Push Notification in Cordova application .I'm using these version of Cordova with plugins :
Cordova version 9.0.0
cordova platform add android@8.0.0
cordova-clipboard
cordova-plugin-androidx
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
cordova-plugin-camera
cordova-plugin-device
cordova-plugin-dialogs
cordova-plugin-document-viewer
cordova-plugin-file
cordova-plugin-file-transfer
cordova-plugin-firebase-lib
cordova-plugin-geolocation
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
cordova-plugin-whitelist
polarcape-cordova-plugin-document-handler
But after using cordova build android I have lots' of debug error .If I remove this plugin I Can to make apk file :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[19.0.   1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

  Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@[19.0.1], but fire   base-iid version was 20.0.2.

  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art   ifact with the issue.   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@19.+   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager@16.0.8   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@17.3.0   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@18.+   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@20.0.2   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@17.+   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@17.3.0   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager@16.+   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-config@18.0.0   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-config@18.+  
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api@16.0.8   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@17.3.0  
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-perf@18.0.1   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@19.0.1

  For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep   endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://   github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b   uild.gradle file.

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

In my Build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase-lib

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4' // fabric dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase-lib
```

Comment: I install this version of plugin and my problem solved.cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib@3.3.0 --save

Comment: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib@3.3.0 --save